# VB.net - Active Directory Connection String

Tags: vb.net

So I have a problem, I can't seem to figure out.
I need a connection string to allow the program to connect to the SQL Server using an Active Directory Account.

However, the Active Directory account is different from the users logged in account, because we don't want to allow the user to have access to SQL just the program...how can I configure the Connection String to use the programs AD account and not the users AD Account?

Comment: you could simply insert the programs AD-Account into the connection string instead of the user AD? Have you tried this? Or please specify your question!

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SQL (mixed) login rather than integrated login if you want to use a dedicated service account for your program.

There is no way to connect to Sql Server using the credentials from an Active Directory account different than the account running the current process. When doing integrated Active Directory authentication, Sql Server only uses the token issued by the domain. It never even sees the password, therefore there is no connection string you can write that will do that login.

The closest you can get is to setup a Scheduled Task in Windows that runs your application as your desired user account. Then you can give other account access to start the task.

Comment: OK, so I think either I didn't explain myself well enough or I'm not understanding your answer...

I'm trying to connect to a SQL database using Integrated Security...however the user running the application DOES NOT have access to the SQL Server therefore it fails.

So how can I connect to a SQL database with the application using AD when the user doesn't have or allowed access to SQL Server?

Comment: @MarkSmith You grant that account access to the server.  **SQL Server does not validate Active Directory credentials.** Ever. When a user logs into a computer connected to Active Directory, they are issued an authentication token. Sql Server integrated authentication will only validate those tokens. Integrated authentication never checks anyone's username or password. The only way to send a token for a different AD user to Sql Server is the run your program as that user (hold down the shift key, right click on a program icon, and use the "Run as different user" option).

Comment: OK, Thanks...I ended up using Impersonation to allow the program to use different AD account from the user currently logged in.